# Upload image using jsGrid through php

Tags: php, image, file, upload, jsgrid

I am stuck on uploading image through jsGrid to my server. I can retrive image from database. But I am facing problem when I upload an Image to my server

Here is my image field

```
        {
        name:"Image",

        edittype:'file',
        align: "center",
       editoptions: {
    enctype: "multipart/form-data"
},

        width: 100,
         itemTemplate: function(val, item) {
            return $("<img>").attr("src", val).css({ height: 80, width: 80 }).on("click", function() {
                $("#imagePreview").attr("src", item.Img);
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        },
        insertTemplate: function() {
            var insertControl = this.insertControl = $("<input>").prop("type", "file");
            return insertControl;
        },
        insertValue: function() {
            return this.insertControl[0].files[0]; 
        }

      },
```

Here is my controller part for inserting item

```
insertItem: function(item){
     var formData = new FormData();
       formData.append("Id", item.Id);
        formData.append("District", item.District);
       formData.append("Category", item.Category);
         formData.append("Name", item.Name);
         formData.append("Path", item.Path);

         formData.append("Description", item.Description);
         formData.append("Description", item.Description);



    formData.append("Image[]", item.Image, item.Image.name);

   return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "fetch_data.php",
    data:formData,
    contentType: false,
        processData: false
   });
  },
```

And here is the php portion

```
$image= $_Files['Image'];
```